# How do I replace the JSON music file in Android UAMP from Android?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am an android Novice.

I am using the Universal Android Media Player sample [code](https://github.com/android/uamp) as basis of another app but I cannot figure out how to update the default music JSON.

The code is in Kotlin. Any help in figuring out where the JSON is and how to update it will be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

The UAMP sample code uses an [external JSON file](https://storage.googleapis.com/uamp/catalog.json) with this format:

```
{
  "music": [
    {
      "id": "wake_up_01",
      "title": "Intro - The Way Of Waking Up (feat. Alan Watts)",
      "album": "Wake Up",
      "artist": "The Kyoto Connection",
      "genre": "Electronic",
      "source": "https://storage.googleapis.com/uamp/The_Kyoto_Connection_-_Wake_Up/01_-_Intro_-_The_Way_Of_Waking_Up_feat_Alan_Watts.mp3",
      "image": "https://storage.googleapis.com/uamp/The_Kyoto_Connection_-_Wake_Up/art.jpg",
      "trackNumber": 1,
      "totalTrackCount": 13,
      "duration": 90,
      "site": "http://freemusicarchive.org/music/The_Kyoto_Connection/Wake_Up_1957/"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

This variable is declared inside the [MusicService.kt](https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/main/common/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/media/MusicService.kt)

```
private val remoteJsonSource: Uri = Uri.parse("https://storage.googleapis.com/uamp/catalog.json")
```

Comment: Please put your code as text instead of links.

Comment: I'm quite new on answering.
I just wrote the links to make a fewer answer direct to the related files.